# render staticfiles django with react redux

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

I have a few objects saved on database that I received by Django RestFramework. That database have a few columns e one of them is ImageField. I already have all setup and my image field's response is "media/product_path.jpg". When I tried render that image field shows me a invalid image, with a image icon and the alt tag. In console from browser don't show the image path and yes the "{product.image}".

```
{ this.props.products.map(product => (
    <tr key={product.id}>
        <th scope="row">
            <img src="{product.image}" alt="product.image" />
        </th>
        <th scope="row">
            {product.name}
        </th>
    </tr>
)) }
```

actions.js

```
export const getProducts = () => dispatch => {

    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/products/')
    .then(response => {
        console.log('response', response)
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCTS,
            payload: response.data
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        return console.log(err);
    });

}
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.19.0",
  "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
  "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
  "react": "^16.9.0",
  "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
  "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
  "react-image": "^2.2.0",
  "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
  "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
  "redux": "^4.0.4",
  "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
},
```

views.py

```
class APIProduct(APIView):
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        products = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    file_serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
    if file_serializer.is_valid():
        file_serializer.save()
        return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('products/', APIProduct.as_view()),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
```

json

```
[
    {
        "id": "b65389f9-357f-4a4e-b3e0-42301772b6f3",
        "name": "Cortina Sunset",
        "slug": "cortina-sunset",
        "description": "Cortina Sunset Descrição",
        "sku": "CODPROD",
        "price_old": "150.00",
        "price": "100.00",
        "image": "/media/products/cortina-sunset.jpg",
        "weight": "1",
        "form": "1",
        "length": "1",
        "height": "1",
        "width": "1",
        "diameter": "1",
        "created_at": "2019-09-05T23:30:28.516456-03:00",
        "modified_at": "2019-09-05T23:32:00.719563-03:00",
        "category": "b2b77854-9714-4010-8d9e-5ffe301af16e"
    }
]
```

Comment: Try `product.image.url`

Comment: Iain, doesn't work..

Comment: What's the rendered value for the `img` `src` and what error are you getting in the browser devt-ools?

Comment: It was supposed to be simple like that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faH5MiX9JJM

Comment: The difference's that it's displaying only one element and directly uses this.props, but I'm displaying a list and should use map

Comment: I try <img src={product.image} alt="product.image" /> too, whitout "